# inequality about the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: inequality

Here I repeat the CRT first. Let $\{m_j\}_{j=1}^k$ be $k$ pairwise coprime positive integers and let $m=m_1m_2\cdots m_k$. Then for any given integer sequence $\{q_j\}_{j=1}^k$, the system of simultaneous equations $x\equiv q_j\pmod{m_j}$, $j=1, 2, \ldots, k$, has a unique solution modulo $m$, which is given by
\begin{equation}
x = \sum_{j=1}^{k} e_j \tilde{m}_j  q_j \mod{m},
\end{equation}
where $\tilde{m}_j=m/m_j$ and $e_j \tilde{m}_j \equiv 1\pmod{m_j}$. In our problem, $e_j$ is the minimal positive inverse of $\tilde{m}_j \bmod {m_j}$, that is $e_j = {\tilde{m}_j}^{\Phi(m_j)-1} \bmod  m_j$, where $\Phi()$ denotes the Euler function.

Then I want to know if there exist a $j$ ($j\in \{1,2,...,k\}$) such that $m>a \cdot e_j \cdot \tilde{m}_j > m/2$, where $a \in \{1,2,3,\ldots,127\}$.

Proof:  $m>a \cdot e_j \cdot \tilde{m}_j > m/2$

$\Longleftarrow$ $\tilde{m}_j \cdot m_j>a \cdot e_j \cdot \tilde{m}_j>\tilde{m}_j \cdot m_j/2$

$\Longleftarrow$ $m_j>a  \cdot e_j > m_j/2$
$\Longleftarrow$ $m_j>a  \cdot ({\tilde{m}_j}^{\Phi(m_j)-1} \bmod  m_j)> m_j/2$

Then I don't know how to prove it next.
If this is not true, can someone provide me a counter-example?

Comment: a) We are talking about residue classes, so nothing keeps you from selecting all $e_j>m$. b) Why should 127 play a special role here?

Comment: a) Changed the definition of $e_j$ to the minimal positive inverse of $\tilde{m}_j \bmod m_j$. b) If $a$ is not bounded, then this is trivial.

Comment: Is my answer at all helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. If $m\le127$, then we can choose $a=m$, making $ae_j\overline{m}_j$ a multiple of $m$, hence, certainly not strictly between $m/2$ and $m$.

Answer (score 0):

The condition 
$$ m> a e_j \tilde m_j>\frac m2 $$
is equivalent to 
$$ q_j > a > \frac{q_j}2,$$
where $q_j=\frac{m_j}{e_j}$. Since $1<e_j<m_j$, we have $q_j>1$.
If $1<q_j<2$, we can select $a=1$.
If $2<q_j$, we have $q_j-\frac{q_j}2>1$, hence there is at least one integer between $\frac{q_j}{2}$ and $q_j$. If more specifically $2<q_j<254$, one of these integers is between $2$ and $127$, inclusive.
If $q_j\ge 254$, it is definitely impossible to find $a\le 127$ with $q_j>a>\frac{q_j}{2}$.
The only remaining case is $q_j=2$, where there is no integer $a$ between $\frac{q_j}2=1$ and $q_j=2$. However, this can only occur with $m_j=2$ as we know that $e_j$ is relatively prime to $m$.

---

Or, to look at it from the other end:
For a given $m_j>2$, consider all $e$ with $\frac{m_j}{254}<e<m_j$, $\gcd(e,m_j)=1$. Then for all $m'$ with $m'\equiv e^{-1}\pmod {m_j}$, the number $m=m_jm'$ has the property we are looking for.